# One or two Wittgensteins?

Tags: wittgenstein

It is common opinion that [Wittgenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein) has two main different periods which are best exemplified by the [*Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus) and the [*Philosophical Investigations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Investigations) and that these periods are highly contradictory. I remember however that a terrific professor, who was my mentor in political philosophy during college, argued that there is a way to read Wittgenstein as a continuation and not a contradiction.

Unfortunately, I lost contact with this professor, so I would like to know if anyone here is familiarized with this argument and can recommend me a good reference to learn more about it. If you also want to comment on why you think it is possible to understand Wittgenstein's work as a continuum or why it is impossible, it will be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A professor of mine ([this guy](http://philosophy.berkeley.edu/sluga/)) once mentioned that [Cora Diamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cora_Diamond) is an advocate of that 'continuum' reading of Wittgenstein. A recent [collection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415173191) edited by Alice Crary and Rupert Read includes a number of such interpretations of Wittgenstein's work (including Diamond's). The interpretations featured in that collection have become collectively known as the ["New Wittgenstein"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Wittgenstein). Perhaps your professor had one of those interpretations in mind.